# Why is it that web developers do not do this with databases?

Tags: encryption, web, passwords

I hear about all these websites getting hacked with sql injections and stuff. What's preventing them from encrypting the hashes with a 32 character string? If I were a hacker and I managed to get the database and I came across encrypted hashes I would not be able to do anything with the database as I do not know the encryption algorithm and the key.

As long as the key being stored securly everyones account would be safe.

Comment: If you can store the key securely, just store the data securely.

Comment: It would be useful to avoid reading how secure password hashing is performed. With a (reversible) encryption the entire system is only as secure as the key; the appropriate use of appropriate password hashing makes it 'infeasible' for (strong) passwords to be recovered within a reasonable time, regardless of some 'secret' key. That being said, there is nothing precluding additional layers of defence. And: if an attacker has found some write access - you already lost.

Comment: See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of encrypting the hashes will indeed improve the security of the users password, but you should understand what exactly you are solving with this measure and what not.

First and most important, encryption on passwords is usually frowned upon, because it is a weak protection. If an attacker has the key, he can instantly discover all passwords. So the encryption does not relieve you from properly hash passwords with a slow algorithm like BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2 or Argon2.

But your question was about *encrypting the hashes*. There is a case where even properly hashed and salted passwords can be recovered easily. If the user has choosen a very weak password, a dictionary attack will reveal them very fast anyway. If the hashes are encrypted though, the attacker needs the key, before he can start with the dictionary. This leads us to the following situation:

Encrypting the hashes will protect weak passwords, as long as the key stays secret. This is always the case when the attacker has no privileges on the server, examples are SQL-injection, disregarded servers, backups, ... I tried to describe this at the end of my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).